# Not a valid xpath expression error for common checkboxes label

Tags: java, selenium

The xpath are showing error as not a valid XPath expression

> '(//label[contains(@class,\"block-label fancy-checkbox\") and
>   contains(text(),\"" +label+
>   "\")]/preceding-sibling::input[@type='checkbox'])[1]' is not a valid
>   XPath expression.

Comment: share your HTML code and the element you need

Comment: instead of escaping `\"` you can simply use `'`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have validated the xpath then use below Xpath:

```
String xpath = "(//label[contains(@class,'block-label fancy-checkbox') and contains(text(),"+label+")]/preceding-sibling::input[@type='checkbox'])[1]";
```

OR

```
String xpath = "(//label[@class='block-label fancy-checkbox' and contains(text(),"+label+")]/preceding-sibling::input[@type='checkbox'])[1]";
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use `String.format` and single quotes:

```
String.format("(//label[contains(@class,'block-label fancy-checkbox') and contains(text(), '%s')]/preceding-sibling::input[@type='checkbox'])[1]", label);
```